# I want flag in my country dropdown

Tags: javascript, wordpress, flags

am using wordpress plugin and it country drop-down work with woocommerce, It showing text country only, Am looking to be with flag My code view is:

if ( ! function_exists( 'wcpbc_manual_country_script' ) ) {

```
function wcpbc_manual_country_script() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){
            $('.wcpbc-widget-country-selecting').on('change', 'select.country', function(){
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            } );
        } );    
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

}

add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'wcpbc_manual_country_script' );

if ( $countries ) : ?>

```
<form method="post" class="wcpbc-widget-country-selecting">     
    <select class="country" name="wcpbc-manual-country">
        <?php foreach ($countries as $key => $value) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key?>" <?php echo selected($key, $selected_country ); ?> ><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>                   
</form>
```

the plugin name is : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-price-based-on-countries/

Comment: is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an image to the options in a select element but you can using this jquery plugin:
http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#IconsandImages

You will need to include;
 - jquery.js
 - jquery-ui.js
 - selectBoxIt.js and
 - selectBoxIt.css

When you loop through each country in your select dropdown you will also need to reference that countries flag image and add it to the "data-iconurl" attribute on the option.

```
<option value="country_value" data-iconurl="flag_image_url">
```

Then initialise the plugin:

```
 $("select.country").selectBoxIt();
```

example:
http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/pNbpGP